# Upgrade to 2.8.1 (fiasco) installed 2.7.3 unable to login to CP

Tags: ee2

Had 2.5.5 install. Upgraded to 2.8.1 which was a disaster.

So I installed 2.7.3

Before i upgraded I turned off the site so it's **offline**

I am unable to login to CP. I don't get an invalid login message it just reloads the login form.

Am in panic mode as I scramble to get access to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing cookies in your browser should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running a config override you can edit:

system>expressionengine>config>config.php with this:

```
$config['is_site_on'] = 'y';
```